# making a general select function for sql library operations

Tags: sql, go, struct

well i am trying to make a select function which will work like this,

From main function i will call this select function with necessary variables. and the select function will run the query in the database and give me the reselt.

Now for go lang if we want to do a select query for the results we need a struct where we can get the results. Since the function will be called from main func and the variables can not be predicted we cant declare a struct before hand so i am stuck here. can anyone give me a solution?

so basically what i am trying to do is we can simply call the query like

-- select name,phone from users where userid=1 ---
so from the main func we will get the values like column name(name,phone), table name (users) and the condition (userid=1)

we will pass these info to the select func and it will run the query and give us back the results.

no matter what is the query is it should work like it. can anyone give me an sample or idea how to work with this

```golang
func select() {
  //DB CONNECTION HERE

type User struct {
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Age     string `json:"age"`
        Email   string `json:"email"`
        Phone   string `json:"phone"`
        Address string `json:"address"`
    }

    results, err := db.Query("SELECT Name, Age, Email, Phone, Address FROM `users` where personId=12 ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for results.Next() {
        var user User
        var email User
        var age User
        var phone User
        var address User

        err = results.Scan(&user.Name, &age.Age, &email.Email, &phone.Phone, &address.Address)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        fmt.Println(user.Name)
        fmt.Println(age.Age)
        fmt.Println(email.Email)
        fmt.Println(phone.Phone)
        fmt.Println(address.Address)
    }
```

Now as zou can see this is the code where we know the query so we made a struct according to it but what about the problem i described above?

Comment: You can use [`rows.Columns`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Columns) and [`rows.ColumnTypes`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.ColumnTypes), with that you can initialize the correct number of variables with the correct struct in the correct order, scan the results into them and then drop that into a map. No need for a struct if your don't want to use one.

Comment: could you please give me an example or a outline of the code that you are talking about?

Comment: Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/uulYPBhokve I haven't tested it so there are probably some bugs but I'm sure you can fix them.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/ODlIxs-XLFE oops the previous version was storing each row into the same map, instead this version stores each row into its own map and then appends the maps to a slice.